# c# многозадачный список коннектов

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Как создать по одному статическому коннекту на каждый поток?
Есть проблема - готовый static класс делает 10 запросов к базе. Каждый connection-open тормозит IIS сервер на 0,3 секунды (итого 3 сек открывается страница). сделал static - connection - получаю исключение на сервере, что connect уже используется другим DataReader (на локальной машине 1 пользователь и проблем нет)

Реализовано свойство типа

```
static SqlConnection _сonn;
static SqlConnection conn {
    if (_conn == null ) _conn = new SqlConnection();
    return _conn
},
```

Вопрос такой, поддерживает ли List многопоточность, какой класс лучше использовать для обвёртки _conn. Можно ли задать что б _conn была по экземпляру на поток а не класс (может флаг какой, volative делает общюю переменную для всех поэтому не то)? Как в с# называется ConcurentList или можно использовать List?

Comment: Вообще, соединения сохраняются в пуле. Второе открытие этой же страницы тоже долго происходит?

Comment: Соединение с одной и той же базой? "Connection Pooling" не выключен? Что-то Вы не договариваете. Повторные соединения должны открываться очень быстро. То, что Вы собираетесь делать, - попытка решать не ту проблему.

Comment: А вы закрываете соединения (вызовом .Close() или using-гом)? Если нет - то физические соединения не возвращаются в пул, и каждый SqlConnection.Open приводит к открытию нового физического соединения - тормозит.

Comment: Узнать бы как-то состояние всех пулов, и с какими именно sql брошены коннекты. PoolList вроде есть, на досуге покопаюсь.  Визуально проблем не вижу, using - стоит везде. Pool=true max=200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо **Alexander Petrov**, я ждал пока он напишет ответ, но напишу сам. Для создание по экземпляру _conn на поток нужно добавить [ThreadStatic] к field-полю с переменной, т.е.

```
[ThreadStatic]
static SqlConnection _сonn;
static SqlConnection conn {
    if (_conn == null ) { 
      _conn = new SqlConnection("ConStr");
      _conn.Open();
      }
    return _conn
},
```

Мою программу это почему-то ускорило.

Answer (score 3):

Класс `SqlConnection` - это не физическое соединение к базе данных. Это способ получить соединение из пулла соединений - уже открытых физических коннекшенов к базе.

Вызов Open открывает новое соединение (и тормозит!) если:

- в пуле вообще нет свободных соединений.
- пулинг соединений вручную вообще выключен в connection string - `Pooling=False`.

В пуле может не быть свободных соединений по двум причинам:

- нагрузка резко растет, и приложению требуется больше одновременно открытых соединений, чем было пару секунд назад.
- вы не возвращаете соединения в пул.

Скорее всего ваши тормоза вызваны последним пунктом - вы не вызываете `.Close` / `.Dispose` у использованных `SqlConnection`, тем самым забирая соединения из пула, но не возвращая их.

Самый простой способ это побороть - обернуть все использования `SqlConnection` в using, тем самым гарантировав вызов Dispose:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    conn.Open();
}
```

Об этом, и о самом механизме пулинга достаточно подробно расписано в [MSDN по SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) и в статье [SQL Server Connection Pooling (ADO.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

То решение, которе пытаетесь внедрить вы, только ухудшит ситуацию:

- вы получите проблемы с одновременным использованием `SqlConnection` в разных потоках.
- вы получите проблемы при разрыве соединений - придется вручную отслеживать и пересоздавать соединения.

Причем обе проблемы будут вызваны как раз долгим использованием класса `SqlConnection` не по назначению - в качестве долгоживущего "реального соединения" а не "временно, на чуть-чуть получить доступ к долгоживущему соединению, и сразу отдать", как он задуман разработчиками.

Comment: Странно, в Debug режиме, как только я поставил static _conn быстродействие увеличилось в 10 раз и локально и на сервере, при том что везде стояло using до изменений. Может SqlDataSource на форме тормозит? Я переписал его коннект.  pooling проверил, там true max=200 min=5. Я попробую и ваш метод и свой - тогда отпишусь.

Comment: @nick_n_a  Раз у вас тормозит, а у остальных - нет - значит вы что-то неправильно делаете :) попробуйте собрать минимальный пример кода и добавить его в вопрос. Такой, который можно будет скопировать в консольное приложение и действительно увидеть что 2-й, 3-й и последующие вызовы Connect тормозят.

Answer (score 1):

Какую именно проблему вы пытаетесь решить многопоточностью?

Может попробовать один batch sql-запрос в одном соединении (с включенным [MARS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
select ...;
select ...;
```

и уже обработку полученных данных распараллелить.

Нет, `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` не поддерживает многопоточность. Возьмите наиболее подходящий класс из пространства имён System.Collections.[Concurrent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx).

Сделать переменную локальной для каждого потока можно с помощью либо класса [ThreadLocal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx), либо атрибута [ThreadStatic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Есть ещё [LocalDataStoreSlot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.localdatastoreslot(v=vs.110).aspx), но это работает медленно. Рекомендуется использовать `ThreadStatic`.

Comment: [ThreadStatic]static SqlConnection _сonn; - хорошее решение, а то я мудрил списками. Правда я не догадался что так его нужно использовать, только что вдруг понял.