# Кто должен отвечать за уничтожение переданных в конструктор другого класса объектов?

Tags: c#, .net

Скажем, есть класс работы с БД.

Ему на вход может быть передан `Connection`. Затем, этот `Connection` запоминается в поле класса и класс работает через него. А можно передать вообще `new Connection()`, тогда ссылка на этот экземпляр будет только в этом классе. Так же может быть еще один конструктор, где строковое предстовление будет передано и я уже в своем конструкторе создам сам `Connection`.

Как правило один объект`Connection`может быть использован параллельно. В MS SQL точно, на сколько я помню, это разрешено.

Так вот, кто в данном случае должен отвечать за уничтожения объекта?

У нас получается 3 случая:

1. `Connection` может быть использоваться параллельно в вызывающем коде
2. `Connection` используется только в 1 классе
3. `Connection` используется только в 1 классе

В первом случае, очевидно, вызывающий код должен быть ответственным, а во втором по идее, сам класс, в третим очевидно мы сами, так как мы собственноручно создали объект из строки => не понятно, как реализовать паттерн `IDiposible`. Хранить где-то флаги? Однако, с флагами опять же не будет понятно, храню ли я только в своем классе ссылку или вызывающий код ее тоже имеет.

Более того- это должно быть очевидно для конечного пользователя, так как класс для него- это черный ящик.

Для примера, если заглянуть в исходники майков:

1. [SqlCommand](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlCommand.cs)
2. [SqlDataReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlDataReader.cs)

, то мы видим, что в первом случае команда не диспозит `Connection`, хотя он хранится в полях класса, а во втором случае так вообще не реализован интерфейс `IDisposible`.

Может быть вообще правильно наружу выставлять подобные ресурсы в `ReadOnly` виде. Тогда сам вызывающий код в любом случае сможет это прибивать?

Еще одним решением я вижу- это в конструкторе задавать `bool` флаг по типу `closeAfterDispose` и тогда мы однозначно сможем определить нужно ли соединение пользователю.

Пример со строкой подключения- это просто один из примеров. Такие же вопросы могут возникнуть при использовании `Stream'ов`, например.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85709/discussion-on-question-by-iluxa1810------).

Comment: Я делал статик коннект - и остался доволен. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538266/c-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2

Comment: Чем случай 2 отличается от случая 3?

Comment: @Qwertiy во втором в метод передается new Connection, а в 3 мы в конструкторе прямо берем и создаем Connection.

Answer (score 7):

Сейчас при построении архитектуры приложения активно применяется *внедрение зависимостей* (Dependency Injection, DI).

В общем случае, внедрение предполагает, что классы получают ссылки друг на друга через конструктор, но не создают и не уничтожают объекты. За создание и уничтожение объектов отвечает такая штука, которую называют IoC-контейнер.

> **Уточнение**. IoC это старое название DI. Подробности о том, почему IoC превратилось в DI читайте в статье Мартина Фаулера, [Inversion of Control Containers and Dependency Injection pattern](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). Это та самая статья, где введён термин Dependency Injection. Вот [вольный перевод](http://yugeon-dev.blogspot.com/2010/07/inversion-of-control-containers-and_21.html) на русский язык.

Чтобы всё это работало, обычно используют библиотеку, такую как Castle, Autofac, Ninject. Всё то же самое можно сделать и вручную, но это будет сложнее и дольше.

Если мы решаем, что именно IoC-контейнер отвечает за создание и уничтожение объектов, вопрос нужно переформулировать: как компоновать классы с разным временем жизни, которые зависят друг от друга? Например, у вас есть `SqlConnection`, который в приложении REST API обычно «живёт» на протяжении HTTP-запроса, а для доступа к данным вы используете какой-нибудь  `OrderRepository`. Репозитории не содержат собственного состояния, поэтому их эффективно создать один раз и просто хранить в течение всего времени работы приложения.

Мы не может передать в конструктор репозитория готовое соединение, его просто не существует. Мы должны создать *фабрику* или *локатор*, скажем, `SqlConnectionFactory`, которую будем вызывать, когда нам потребуется подключение. Фабрика создаёт нам новый объект, и, если он *disposable*, мы должны освободить его в том же методе, пользуясь оператором `using`. *Локатор* находит готовый объект, и мы не должны его освобождать сами.

Для конкретного примера возьмём библиотеку Autofac. Для начала опишем зависимости между классами/интерфейсами.

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
{
    private readonly Func<SqlConnection> _locateSqlConnection;

    public OrderRepository(Func<SqlConnection> locateSqlConnection)
    {
        _locateSqlConnection = locateSqlConnection;
    }

    public Order ReadById(int id)
    {
        var connection = _locateSqlConnection();

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            // Здесь загружаем данные, конструируем Order и возвращаем его
            . . .
            return new Order(id, createdAt, amount);
        }
    }

    . . .
}
```

Здесь показано, как *локатор* может быть описан в Autofac. Когда будет вызвана функция `_locateSqlConnection`, Autofac вернёт существующее подключение, создав его, если его не было.

Если ответственность за создание `SqlConnection` лежит на библиотеке Autofac, она же должна освободить объект. По умолчанию, Autofac сохраняет все ссылки на созданные `IDisposable` объекты и освобождает их, когда контейнер больше не нужен. Контейнеров в программе может быть несколько, и Autofac умеет создавать специальный контейнер для HTTP-запроса.

Для разных запросов будут созданы разные контейнеры и, соответственно, разные экземпляры `SqlConnection`. Чтобы это всё работало, достаточно правильно описать «время жизни» при регистрации репозитория в Autofac.

```
builder.Register<OrderRepository>()
       .As<IOrderRepostitory>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

`OrderRepository` это singleton, который будет создан один раз.

`SqlConnection` создаётся один раз на HTTP-запрос:

```
builder.Register<SqlConnection>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

А что с `SqlCommand`? `SqlCommand` мы создаём сами в рамках метода `OrderRepository.ReadById`, поэтому и освобождать его мы должны сами.

Подробнее о DI/IoC можно почитать в книге [Внедрение зависимостей в .NET](https://www.litres.ru/mark-siman/vnedrenie-zavisimostey-v-net-11869911/). В сети бродит PDF, но ссылку давать не буду, потому что не знаю, как там с авторскими правами.

Comment: Вы путаете термины **DIP (Dependency Inversion Principle)** и **DI (Dependency Injection)**. 

У вас есть грубая ошибка. Вы говорите "IoC это старое название DI". Это неверно! Термин **IoC (Inversion of Control)** эквивалентен термину DIP. А DI - частный случай IoC.
Это разные термины, и хоть они тесно связаны, нельзя их путать.

Comment: **DIP или IoC (Инверсия зависимостей)** - это один из принципов SOLID, про то, что абстракции не должны зависеть от деталей, а наоборот, детали должны зависеть от абстракций. Используется он для уменьшения зацепления в программном коде.

**DI (Dependency Injection)** - это как раз то, о чём вы рассказываете. И это частный случай DIP.

Comment: @Gordory, Спасибо, подправил.

Comment: Я всё еще считаю, что есть неразбериха с этими терминами. Но на самом деле теперь это уже проблема сообщества. Потому что IoC как термин изначально был синонимом DIP а потом превратился в синоним DI. Хотя DI, как я писал - частный случай DIP.
Текущий вариант вашего ответа хорош.

Comment: @Gordory Я в любом случае допустил ошибку, написав Dependency Inversion там, где должно было быть написано Dependency Injection. Благодаря Вам, ошибка исправлена.

Answer (score -1):

Надеюсь, что вопрос понял правильно :)

На сколько я понимаю GarbageCollector(GC) важно количество ссылок на обьект с разных мест.

То есть, если на некий обьект ссылается еще хотя бы один обьект - он не будет уничтожен.

Так же есть обьекты которые нужно принудительно уничтожать из памяти, до того как их захавает GC. Они наследуются через iDisposable. У них нужно вызывать Dispose() для того, что бы очистить вручную не дожидаясь когда это сделает GC. В основном это используется для больших обьектов, например, картинок. Что б прога не жрала памяти по пару гигабайт на пустом месте, до момента, пока не проработает GC :)

> Connection может быть использоваться параллельно в вызывающем коде

Он будет помечен на освобожденние как только закончится работа ОБЕИХ методов - и вызывающего и вызываемого.

А освобожден во время вызова GC.

В случае если это конекшн, то он наследуется от IDisposable только в случае, если ты хочешь сделать нагрузку на БД меньшей. То есть сделать так, что бы к ней было приконекчено как можно меньше пользователей одновременно. Если же проэкт маленький изначально, то с этим можно и не запариватся.

> Connection используется только в 1 классе

Он будет помечен на освободление как только закончится этот метод. И будет диспоузонут автоматически при вызове GC.

Ну или, лучше, диспоузонуть вручную (раз уж гарантированно!!! не затронет ничего лишнего)

---

Вызывать Dispose() ты должен только в том случае, когда ты уверен что конекшн никем более не используется. Если же такой уверенности нет - лучше отдать эту обязанность на GC.

И в случае с конекшнами к базам данных, хочу напомнить что базы данных сами могут обрывать конекшн по таймауту. То есть если клиент не отзывается некоторое время, то сервер перестает с ним работать.

Comment: "И будет диспоузонут автоматически при вызове GC." - "Вы погубите себя, мой юный друг!" А.Дюма "Три мушкетера"

Comment: К примеру, SqlConnection не закрывается автоматически при сборке мусора. Только вручную.

Comment: Да, описанный у вас способ вызовет утечку памяти. И это будет критично в  программах, которые, например, должны работать непрерывно.